# Great arc distance between two points on a unit sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Suppose I have two points on a unit sphere whose spherical coordinates are $(\theta_1, \varphi_1)$ and $(\theta_2, \varphi_2)$. What is the great arc distance between these two points?

I found something from Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas) but it is written in terms of latitude and longitude instead. I wonder latitude is $\pi/2 - \theta$ and longitude is $\varphi$. Am I right?

[image: spherical coordinates]

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So I can just plug these into the equation on Wiki and compute the great arc distance, right?

Comment: latitude $\theta$ is measured from equator, not from the north pole as in your figure

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the two vectors to the points on the sphere,
$${\bf v}_i=(r\sin\theta_i\cos\varphi_i,r\sin\theta_i\sin\varphi_i,r\cos\theta_i)$$
with $i=1,2$. Use the dot product to get the angle $\psi$ between them:
$${\bf v}_1\cdot {\bf v}_2=r^2\left(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\left(\varphi_1-\varphi_2\right)\right)=r^2\cos\psi.$$

Then the arclength is
$$s=r\psi=r\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\left(\varphi_1-\varphi_2\right)\right).$$

Comment: how exactly you got the dot product ?

Comment: What you get is not the formula from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas . I can't understand how the differences in cos are derived since you compute the inner product

Comment: @curious the Wikipedia coordinates are defined differently than those in the question posted here.

Comment: Even if without the wikipedia definition i cant see how the formula of inner product between $v_1$ and $v_2$ gives the result you wrote

Comment: @curious $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ and $\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\cos(\alpha-\beta)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are \varphi_1 and \varphi_2 angles? If I use 0 for both \theta_1 and \theta_2, I get a 0 degree difference no matter what \varphi_1 and \varphi_2 are. That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @BT if $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$ then both points are the north pole and there is no distance between them regardless of $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$. I follow the angle definitions made by the diagram in the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Got it, someone else helped me figure that out. I was misunderstanding how spherical coordinates worked. Thanks!

Comment: if the points are diametrically opposite lying on the equator i.e. $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$ & $\phi_1-\phi_2=\pi$ then distance should be $\pi r$ but your formula doesn't hold good.

Comment: @Bhaskara-III with the coordinates as defined here, the two points you are describing are both at the north pole and the formula correctly shows a distance of zero.

Answer (score 1):

I compare two formulas in Matlab, in terms of precision and running time.

Consider the sphere, in Cartesian coordinates:

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \rho^2$

or in spherical coordinates:

$x = \rho \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi)\\
y = \rho \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi)\\
z = \rho \cos(\theta)$

Choose a bunch of points on the sphere, for example:

```
N = 1e6 + 1;
rho_sph = rand;
phi_sph = rand(N, 1) * pi;
theta_sph = rand(N, 1) * pi;

xyz_sph = [rho_sph * sin(theta_sph) .* cos(phi_sph), ...
           rho_sph * sin(theta_sph) .* sin(phi_sph), ...
           rho_sph * cos(theta_sph)];
```

Now calculate the distance between each couple of points (1,2), (2,3), ..., (N-1, N).

1º formula

```
tic
aa = cross(xyz_sph(1:end-1, :), xyz_sph(2:end, :));
bb = dot(xyz_sph(1:end-1, :)', xyz_sph(2:end, :)');
aa = arrayfun(@(n) norm(aa(n, :)), 1:size(aa, 1));
d1 = rho_sph * atan2(aa, bb)';
toc
% Elapsed time is 12.376257 seconds.
```

2º formula

```
tic
d2 = rho_sph * acos(cos(theta_sph(1:end-1)) .* cos(theta_sph(2:end)) + ...
     sin(theta_sph(1:end-1)) .* sin(theta_sph(2:end)) .* ...
     cos(phi_sph(1:end-1) - phi_sph(2:end)));
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.264629 seconds.
```

The first formula is considered more precise, but it's slower; the second is less accurate at the poles, but it's much faster. Otherwise the two solutions are practically equivalent:

```
plot(d1 - d2, '.')
```

Comment: Does the expense of the first formula decrease if you store `xyz_sph(2:end, :)` as an intermediate value instead of computing it twice?

Answer (score 1):

well, i see Wikipedia says there is serious rounding error in the formula of top answer. i found on google a new [formula with the derivation](http://www.academia.edu/27998203/Minimum_distance_between_any_two_arbitrary_points_on_the_sphere_of_a_finite_radius_or_globe_given_the_latitudes_and_longitudes_Application_of_HCRs_cosine_formula_). It seems slightly complicated but it is correct one. you can calculate values of distance & compare with percentage errors in both the formula.
i hope it will help you