How to calculate the distance between a spherical coordinate and a longitude line
How to Calculate Great-Circle Distance to a Longitude Line?
In a spherical coordinate system (e.g., Earth's latitude and longitude):

I have a point $(\phi, \lambda)$ (latitude and longitude, respectively).
I also have a fixed longitude line (defined by a single $\lambda_0$).

I want to calculate the great-circle distance from the point to the longitude line. Specifically, this is the distance along the surface of the sphere to the closest point on the longitude line.
My Thoughts

Initially, I thought this is the same as the distance between $(\phi, \lambda)$ and $(\phi, \lambda_0)$, but I realized this is incorrect except at the equator.
I believe the correct answer involves finding the great-circle path that is perpendicular to the longitude line, but I am unsure how to compute this.

Question
How can I calculate this great-circle distance? What is the formula or method?

Perhaps this may prove useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833002/distance-between-two-points-in-spherical-coordinates

@CW279 I could find the formula for distance between two points but it's unclear to me how to derive the formula I need here from this.

---Edited 18 Nov 2024: The previous calculation of $B$, the bearing to the point of intersection with the specified line of longitude, was incomplete.  This has now been corrected.---
The natural tool for such problems is Spherical Trigonometry.

The figure above depicts a typical spherical triangle. The sides of the triangle are arcs of great circles.  A great circle is the intersection of the sphere with a plane that passes through the center of the sphere.  Unlike plane triangles, the sides of the triangle ($a, b$ and $c$) are measured in radians or degrees, not linear units. I'll assume we are using radians throughout.
For your question, let's suppose vertex $A$ is at the North Pole and your location is vertex $B$ with co-latitude $\phi_0$ and longitude $\lambda_0$.  The co-latitude is zero at the North Pole and $\pi/2$ at the equator, unlike geographical latitude which is $\pi/2$ at the North Pole and zero at the equator.  Further suppose that $b$ is the line of longitude you want to reach with longitude $\lambda_1$, and $C$ is a right angle.  We want to find $a$, the least spherical distance from your location to the designated line of longitude.
To this end, we may apply the Spherical Law of Sines in the form
$$\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$$
Here $A = \lambda_1 - \lambda_0$, $C= \pi/2$, and $c = \phi_0$, so
$$\frac{\sin(\lambda_1 - \lambda_0)}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin{\pi/2}}{\sin \phi_0}$$
which is easily solved for $\sin a$.  Taking the inverse sine then yields $a$.  If you want the terrestrial distance, find $a$ in radians and multiply $a$ by the radius of the earth.
A natural question is what is the measure of $B$, the bearing from your location to $C$?  This is a two-step process. First, for a spherical triangle in which $C$ is a right triangle, the following identity holds:
$$\cos c = \cos a \cos b$$
(This is rule R1 in the Wikipedia article on Spherical Trigonometry.) Since we know $a$ and $c$, we can now solve for $\cos b$ and calculate $b$.
Second, we may apply the Spherical Law of Cosines in the form
$$\cos b = \cos a \cos c + \sin a \sin c \cos B$$
Since we now know $a, b$ and $c$, this equation may be easily solved for $\cos B$.

@DavidK Oops! Corrected now, I think.  Thank you.

I think that checks out. So if I understand correctly, if I use geographical coordinates the only difference is that instead of sin(phi) I'll have sin(phi/2 - fi) aka cos(phi)?
Another question is - shouldn't you take the absolute value of the difference in lambdas because it may be negative and will produce a negative distance? I don't think you can assume one of the lambdas are bigger than the other.
Another side note that you might want to edit is be more consist with the parameters names. You sometimes use 0 and 1 and sometimes 1 and 2. It confused me a little bit when I was reading.

@ShacharHar-Shuv You are correct about the use of co-latitude versus latitude.  Sorry about the inconsistent variable names--I think I have fixed those now.  Thank you for pointing them out.  As for the the question of whether the computations may yield a negative distance, I wouldn't worry about it.  Just think of it as a directed distance, like the distance from $2$ to $1$ on the real line ($-1$).
