# Spherical distance between two points in terms of latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

I have seen the answer to this question - [Great arc distance between two points on a unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/great-arc-distance-between-two-points-on-a-unit-sphere)

However in a fortran program that I have this is the code to calculate spherical distance between two points - presuming lambda is longitude and theta is latitude

arg=$\sin\theta_1$ * $\sin\theta_2$ + $\cos\theta_1$ *$\cos\theta_2$ * $\cos(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)$

$dis=radius*acos(arg)$

The identity referenced in the linked answer is given below. Can these be shown to be equivalent ?

$\cos\theta_1$  $\cos\theta_2$ + $\sin\theta_1$  $\sin\theta_2$ $\cos(\psi_1 - \psi_2)$

Comment: It would be useful if you included here the formula you're interested in from the referenced post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed both the formulae are identical. This can be shown in the following manner.

In the spherical polar coordinate system  $\theta$ polar angle  is the angle between the zenith direction and a line segment OP. But $\theta$ is nothing but the co latitude. 
Since we do know that latitude

$\theta$ = 90 - colatitude and also $\cos(90 - \theta)$ = $\sin\theta$. Substituting this into the original identity reveals that the identities are equal.