# How can I get the angle between two 2-component 3d angles?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

If I have two 3d angles like `[120 degrees, 40 degrees]` and `[70 degrees, 90 degrees]`, how would I calculate the scaler angle between them? All the related answers I see on here are about vectors with lengths, but I just have angles.

UPDATE:

I wrote this program based on Lewis's answer, but I don't think its right.

```
var deg = Math.PI/180
var sin = Math.sin, cos = Math.cos, acos = Math.acos, pow = Math.pow

var cpointA = {r:1, a1: 120*deg, a2: 0*deg}
var cpointB = {r:1, a1: 90*deg, a2: 0*deg}

var pointA = cartesianFromSpherical(cpointA)
var pointB = cartesianFromSpherical(cpointB)

function angleBetween(pointA, pointB) {
  return acos(dot(pointA,pointB)/(mag(pointA)*mag(pointB)))
}

function dot(a,b) {
  return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z
}

function mag(point) {
  var x = point.x, y = point.y, z = point.z
  return pow(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2), .5) 
}

function cartesianFromSpherical(sphericalPoint) {
  var r = sphericalPoint.r, a1 = sphericalPoint.a1, a2 = sphericalPoint.a2
  return {
    x: r * sin(a1)*cos(a2),
    y: r * sin(a1)*sin(a2),
    z: r * cos(a1)
  }
}

function radiansFromDeg(xDegrees) {
  return xDegrees*deg
}
function degreesFromRad(radians) {
  return radians/deg
}

theta = angleBetween(pointA,pointB)
degreesFromRad(theta)
```

This gives the expected answer of 30 degrees. But if I switch a1 and a2 by changing my points to:

```
var cpointA = {r:1, a1: 0*deg, a2: 120*deg}
var cpointB = {r:1, a1: 0*deg, a2: 90*deg}
```

I get 0 degrees. I'd still expect 30 degrees. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

Lewis helped me understand that my program above is written correctly and I was just misunderstanding the spherical coordinates.

Comment: Try using spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Lewis That sounds like the right thing to do. Looking into that, the answers related to finding an angle aren't very clear. I found the top answer here which I don't fully understand: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/great-arc-distance-between-two-points-on-a-unit-sphere . I calculate a 0 degree difference if theta1 and theta2 are 0, no matter what phi1 and phi2 are. I must be misunderstanding that somehow..

Answer (score 2):

Your can consider those two points on a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and convert their coordinates to Cartesian using the the following:$$x=r\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}, y=r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi},z=r\cos{\theta}$$
and then use $v\cdot w=|v||w|\cos(\psi)$ to calculate the angle $\psi$ between them.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for me in doing that: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

Comment: Ugh, I'm still getting the same result with a completely different method. If I switch theta and phi I get different answers. Is that expected?

Comment: I added the way I'm coming to that answer into my question.

Comment: In your code, why did you put $0$*deg in the third coordinate? How did you define the angles in your original question? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Is 0 not a valid angle? I'm essentially smoke testing this 3d equation by putting in two lines that are in the same place - and so are easy to verify with 2d analysis.

Comment: Yes, the results given by your code completely make sense. Think about what $\theta$ and $\phi$ mean: they are the angles between the vector and the z-axis and x-axis respectively.

Comment: Because the z and x axes are perpendicular, I would think the situation is symmetric. Knowing that theta is angle from x and phi is angle from z aren't helping me understand what's going on. Why would the angle between my second two vectors be 0 when they have different a2 (phi) angles? It still doesn't make sense.

Comment: If your angle between the vector and the z-axis is zero, that means your vector is restricted to the z-axis. In that situation it does not matter what your angle between the vector and x-axis is. (Draw a graph you will see this very clearly.)

Comment: Ok, looking again at the spherical coordinate wikipedia article helps. I understand you now. That does make sense. Thanks! I'll accept your answer if you add a little more details as to how to use the dot product to calculate the angle - for future readers.